# Save all file names in a directory to a vector

Tags: c++

I need to save all ".xml" file names in a directory to a vector.  To make a long story short, I cannot use the dirent API.  It seems as if C++ does not have any concept of "directories".

Once I have the filenames in a vector, I can iterate through and "fopen" these files.

Is there an easy way to get these filenames at runtime?

Comment: what compiler are you using and which operating system is your target for? Because there's no an unique way to gather file from a directory.. with windows you should use win32 api while on unix/osx (any posix compliant) you should use dirent as you mentioned..

Comment: You could, I guess, use the boost::filesystem abstraction, though I personally am not a fan of boost.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: The suggestions here to use boost::filesystem instead of dirent, are not valid. boost::filesystem gives a cross-platform view of the filesystem, but on Unix platforms it will use dirent underneath.

In fact the only "standard" way to do what you want on Unix platforms is to use dirent at the lowest level. Can you explain why you cannot use dirent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (Note, Format is a sprintf:ish funciton you can replace)

```
bool MakeFileList(const wchar_t* pDirectory,vector<wstring> *pFileList)
{
    wstring sTemp = Format(L"%s\\*.%s",pDirectory,L"xml");

    _wfinddata_t first_file;

    long hFile = _wfindfirst(sTemp.c_str(),&first_file);

    if(hFile != -1)
    {
        wstring sFile = first_file.name;
        wstring sPath = Format(L"%s%s",pDirectory,sFile.c_str());
        pFileList->push_back(sPath);

        while(_wfindnext(hFile,&first_file) != -1)
        {
            wstring sFile = first_file.name;
            wstring sPath = Format(L"%s%s",pDirectory,sFile.c_str());
            pFileList->push_back(sPath);
        }
        _findclose(hFile);
    }else
        return false;

    return true;    
}
```

Comment: _wfindfirst doesn't look like part of C++ Standard.

Comment: Took a wild guess that it was Windows

Answer (score 8):

Easy way is to use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library.

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
// ...
std::string path_to_xml = CUSTOM_DIR_PATH;
std::vector<string> xml_files;
fs::directory_iterator dir_iter( static_cast<fs::path>(path_to_xml) ), dir_end;
for (; dir_iter != dir_end; ++dir_iter ) {
  if ( boost::iends_with( boost::to_lower_copy( dir_iter->filename() ), ".xml" ) )
    xml_files.push_back( dir_iter->filename() );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest having a look at [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) if it should be portable and bringing boost in isn't too heavy.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like boost, try Poco.  It has a DirectoryIterator.  http://pocoproject.org/